# Remap the default hotkey for inserting keyframes

Tags: animation

Is there a possibility to override the default hotkey <kbd>I</kbd> for inserting keyframes for a parameter currently under the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

You can change any Blender hotkey in the user preferences.  Just open the user prefrances menu (File > User Preferences or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and go to the Input tab, then find the hotkey you want to change.

Comment: Seems like inserting the keyframe via controls is a different case: https://developer.blender.org/T49415